# What can be done about someone deleting the body of my answer?

Tags: discussion

A user with a reputation of 3 ([Naelin](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5307/naelin)) deleted the text of [my answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/do-car-alarms-provide-a-significant-reduction-in-automobile-theft) and substituted their own.  There was an issue with my citation (it is fixed now), but deleting the text of my answer was not the solution.

Does this case highlight a flaw, or is reversion the one and only answer?

EDIT:

The deleted text:

> The insurance data are unequivocal. In 1997, the non-profit Highway Loss Data Institute (HLDI) surveyed insurance-claims data from 73 million vehicles, to see which devices could prevent theft. Looking at cars from many different model years, across the country, the study concludes that cars with alarms "show no overall reduction in theft losses" compared to cars without alarms.

The added text:

> There are a variety of antitheft and tracking systems on the market with costs ranging from basic audible alarms costing $50 to sophisticated tracking systems with $30 monthly fees. Unfortunately, the effectiveness of many of these devices is questionable. The sensitivity of audible alarms to touch or movement, for example, provokes a “boy who cried wolf” reaction. When a car alarm goes off, people tend not to react because the alarms activate so frequently for reasons other than actual theft. HLDI studies show no overall reduction in theft losses for vehicles with such alarms.

Answer (score 3):

The edit improved your answer, by adding a link and a correct citation, while not changing the meaning of it in the least.

Regarding the edit itself, it was approved by me.

Stackexchange sites are different from other QA sites in that they are collaboratively edited. Improving other people's contribution is welcome and expected. We even have seven [badges](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/badges) for it :-)

The policy is in our FAQ: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#editing

> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!

[...]

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification regarding the choice to make this site open to anyones edits regardless of reputation.  I went ahead and added the specific change that was made to my post.  Does this really look like it does not change the meaning to you?

Comment: @SeanVikoren yes: they both mean that car alarms are ineffective.

Comment: A bit more back-story: I added a comment requesting the change - the quote was misattributed. Naelin suggested it. Sklivvz approved it. Someone posted a comment confused by my (now obsolete) comment which started a confused conversation and explanation. In accordance with StackExchange recommendations, I deleted the obsolete comments.